# Osm2pgql failed to output expired tiles for "delete" operation when running in cron

Tags: osm2pgsql, delete

I am using osm2pgsql to:

1. Append .osc files into gis rendering database (based on mod_tile / Mapnik stack) to "delete" some features
2. Generate expired tiles list via -e -o options
3. Fed the expired tiles list to render_expired to re-render the tiles

I run all the steps in an script via crontab as the user myself.

The weird thing is:

- a. When I run the script manually via login shell (bash), the expired list comes out as expected.
- b. However, after run in the crontab job, for osm changes "delete", the .osc file is generated property, but the expired list is always "empty"!

Anyone met with this kind of problem before?

The keys here lie in:

1. osm2pgsql run by crontab in a bash script
2. .osc file is not empty
3. Only "delete" changes works wrong
4. pgsql database log shows "delete" statement works properly (so as for login & other operations)
5. I hacked osm2pgsql code, by the logging, m_dirty_tiles is not empty when pasring .osc xml

Comment: Also reported here: https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/1268

Comment: Yup, thanks for pasting here

Comment: The way you describe the problem here, it's impossible to give any advice, as most important parts are missing. Unfortunately, the details in the Github issue are also not that clear. Try to break down the whole process into smaller steps and validate each step on its own first.